# How do I make rosinstall just install the one package I want

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've gotten used to doing:

```
roslocate info $package > /tmp/$package.rosinstall; yes s | rosinstall ~/ros /tmp/$package.rosinstall
```

but this results in rosinstall going through **every** custom package I've installed and updating it. I have some conflicts in packages that I don't really want to update, so the 'yes s' is necessary so I don't have to babysit the process. This is particularly annoying since my list of installed packages is only going to get bigger as time goes on.

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way to install third-party stacks? rosinstall is so close to being perfect

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9701/how-do-i-make-rosinstall-just-install-the-one-package-i-want/) by [froody](https://answers.ros.org/users/369/froody/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no option to update just a single checkout as rosinstall's purpose is to achieve the state of the system asked of it by the .rosinstall file.

I would suggest that you can update the .rosinstall file to point to the checkout which you are working against such that it does not conflict anymore.  Rosinstall doesn't check for local changes if it has the same URL/branch combo.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can always just run svn (or git) directly:

```
$ svn up ~/ros/$package
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2